# How to resolve Windows 10 notifications

Tags: windows-10, notifications

I just updated my windows build from 1709 to 1803, and I knew I might get some errors.
 So after the update I get a message about an app that is not compatible with the new updated system. the name of the app appears in the notification, but after I have clicked it it takes me to this site:
[windows-10-app-not-work](https://support.microsoft.com/us-en/help/10581/windows-10-app-not-work) and the notification disappears.
 By this time I don't remember what the name of the app was, and the notification is gone.
 How is this helpfull to me?

> How can I find out the name of the app that is not compatible anymore?

Comment: Look Windows logs (system or application, I don't remember) for it.

Comment: Nice I haven't used Windows Logs before but I found them in the EventViewer, and I must say the logs in them are great! Now I can see everything that has crashed and more. Thanks.

Comment: Even though the logs were  a great new asset, I really could not find which app were not compatible anymore.